# Change Text on mouse hover of a link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, mousehover, textchanged

I am designing a wordpress website and would like to change a text underneath a set of links. I already found this treat and it looked promising:
[Solution to problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344921/how-to-change-text-box-content-on-hover/24344993#24344993)

Unfortunatey, this solution does not work for me. I included the CSS using the "Simple Custom CSS" plugin and included the html code like it is presented in the example. The links are there, but no text gets displayed. When I leave the "display: none" part out, I see all three text blocks. What am I doing wrong?

My code in the page file:

```
<a href="#" class="a-1">one</a>
<a href="#"class="a-2">two</a>
<a href="#"class="a-3">three</a>
<div class="element-1">hello one</div>
<div class="element-2">hello two</div>
<div class="element-3">hello three</div>
```

My code in the custom css file:

```
.element-1, .element-2, .element-3{
     display: none;
}
.a-1:hover  ~ .element-1 {
     display: block;
}
.a-2:hover  ~ .element-2{
     display: block;
}
.a-3:hover  ~ .element-3 {
     display: block;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've done already:) by posting your code

Comment: Alright, I updated my question with the code.

Comment: Ok and now, what do you want the code to do when hover on one, two or three

Comment: To change a text underneath the code, like "You hovered link 1" or "This leads to site blablabla"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kyamct30/  your code works? edit -> Do you understand what the code does?

Comment: The code seems logical to me but it doesn't work. It just won't display anything when hovering over a link. When I leave out the "display: none" part, all three "You hovered...." get displayed so the code gets executed but sth is not working as it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from moesphemie:

Hey check this question about the ~ [stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-css-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-selector-do) Try to put the a's and the elements in one div, maybe the wrapping p cuts the connection between those elements

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is not working for you: (Can't be sure since u have not linked your code)

```
<a href="#" class="a-1">one</a>
```

`<div class="element-1">hello one</div>`

Are you sure you imported the same classes?

and here might be the problem : `class="a-1"` & `class="element-1"` for you,
if you want the link to change color on mouseover you should simply use

```
a:hover { 
    color: yellow;
}
```

If you want to have a color for all options:

```
a:link {
    color: #B2FF99;
}

a:visited {
    color: #FEFEFE;
}

a:hover {
    color: #323232;
}

a:active {
    color: #121211;
}
```

article: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't want to change the color of the link. I would like to change a text [elsewhere] when hovering over a link.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, if not let me know.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a:link {
    background-color: #B2FF99;
}

a:visited {
    background-color: #FFFF85;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #FF704D;
}

a:active {
    background-color: #FF704D;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b><a href="default.asp" target="_blank">This is a link</a></b></p>

</body>
</html>
```

[Test this code here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_link_background)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but see my comment to Katherina

Answer (score 0):

[image: WP-Style]
Take a look at my WP-Backend (German, sorry ;) )

Navigate from 1 to 2 - in this file >style.css< you can edit your website's style.

In 3 paste your code. Remember to use the same id's and classes for your elements!

However like Katherina mentioned, we need to see your code!

Comment: The code is exactly this:
http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/p7WUu/

Including it to this file did not help, either.

Comment: Of course this one works - But what we need to see is the output form your wordpress-site, where do you want to embed it - maybe a !important will do the job

Comment: I tried the !important already. The output can be tested here:
http://wordpress.slipstreamgx.com/weaponry/

Comment: Hey check this question about the ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-css-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-selector-do 
Try to put the a's and the elements in one div, maybe the wrapping p cuts the connection between those elements

Comment: Awesome. Placing <div> around the HTML code solved the problem. How can I mark your comment as answer?
Thanks alot :)

Comment: haha yeah great :) I think there must be somewhere a green checkmark for this - glad that i could help you and good luck for everything with your project