# How To Change Text Box Content On Hover of a Fixed block? (Other solution didn't work)

Tags: html, css, hover

So I followed the other topic's solution but the Description I set still doesn't want to appear in the text box.

I already tried this: [How To Change Text Box Content On Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344921/how-to-change-text-box-content-on-hover)
I double checked every class name every bracket in the css I just but still nothing. What could be the problem?

Relevant part of the code:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:link {
  color: #3ea500;
}

.a-1:hover~.element-1 {
  display: block;
}

.a-2:hover~.element-2 {
  display: block;
}

.a-3:hover~.element-3 {
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  color: #cc7400;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.desc {
  background-color: green;
  width: 33%;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 66%;
  top: 180px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="desc">
    Description:
    <div class="element-1">hello one</div>
    <div class="element-2">hello two</div>
    <div class="element-3">hello three</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="a-1" href="#" target="_blank">Deepdream generator.</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="a-2" href="#" target="_blank">Picture Breeder</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="a-3" href="#" target="_blank">AI guesses what you draw</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Expected: The text appears in the description Box.

Results: Nothing happens.

Maybe the browser is bad?

Comment: `~` is [the general sibling combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10782297/215552). You've change the HTML of the answer such that the elements are no longer siblings.

Comment: `a-1:hover ~ .element-1` etc. You simply can not do that because your .a-1 placed below .element-1. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator

Comment: The rule: X ~ Y => Selects every Y element that is **preceded** by a X element. Your 'targeted' `.element-x` classes precede the 'selecting' classes `.a-x` instead of the other way around. Secondly, when you have corrected that, you will see that the 'targeted' elements are preceded by a `<ul>` (not the `<a>`) and just are not at the same nesting level as their 'selectors'. It will not work this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:Hover does not trigger some 'click', 'tap' or 'swipe' event, otherwise you could have used the `:target` selector ([W3Schools on :target](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp)). However, have a look at my code and you will see that I made the 'targeted' text a child inside the `<a>` element and initially hide that.

On the 'hover' the targeted text gets positioned '`absolute`' below the 'Description' and `display: block`'ed. That's basically all that there is to it. Tiny little trick, vanilla CSS and no Javascript required...

And...you will still have your '`<ul><li>`' structure intact.

When I get stuck on something I always track back and simplify.

**Update 1:**

When you want the 'targeted' text inside a 'Description' box, just increase the height of that box and it will be placed on top of that when you add `z-index: 1` to the `.target` class...

**Update 2:**

Search for 'css stacking context' to learn about `z-index` and how to 'layer' your documents.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:link, a:visited {
  color: #3ea500;
}
a:hover {
  color: #cc7400;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.desc {
  background-color: green;
  width: 33%;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 66%;
  top: 180px; height: 38px /*update*/
}

a>.target       { display: none; z-index: 1 /*update*/ }
a:hover>.target { display: block; position: absolute; left: 66%; top: 199px; color: black }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Deepdream generator.    <span class="target">hello one  </span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Picture Breeder         <span class="target">hello two  </span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">AI guesses what you draw<span class="target">hello three</span></a></li>
</ul>

<div class="desc">Description</div>
```

**Alternate:** apart from the link you already tried: if you don't like the `<span>` in your `<a>`, make the 'targeted' elements also a `<li>` inside the `<ul>` you already have. Initially hide them and place them elsewhere when its 'selecting' `<a>` is hovered.

Same result, slightly different code:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:link, a:visited {
  color: #3ea500;
}
a:hover {
  color: #cc7400;
  font-weight: 700;
}
a:hover {
  color: #cc7400;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.desc {
  background-color: green;
  width: 33%;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 66%;
  top: 180px;
  height: 38px /*add*/
}

.target            { display: none; z-index: 1 }
li:hover + .target { display: block; position: absolute; left: 66%; top: 199px; color: black }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Deepdream generator.</a></li>
    <li class="target">hello one</li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Picture Breeder</a></li>
    <li class="target">hello two</li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">AI guesses what you draw</a></li>
    <li class="target">hello three</li>
</ul>

<div class="desc">Description</div>
```